# How to set Look and Feel in Groovy (SwingBuilder)?

Tags: swing, user-interface, groovy

I've been trying to set **L&F** for groovy swing application but no clue. I want pure **groovy** answer (Lessen my Java code in the project).

sample code:

```
SwingBuilder sb = new SwingBuilder()
def addItmMenu= sb.frame(title:"New Item Menu",
    size: [400,350],
    resizable: false,
    locationRelativeTo: null,
    defaultCloseOperation:WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE){

    label(text:"Example Look and Feel Groovy")
}
```

Comment: @downvoter There is no answer for this question here !!.. Before down voting make your point in a comment !! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use normal swing mechanics for this:

```
UIManager.lookAndFeel = "javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel"

def sb = new SwingBuilder()
def addItmMenu = sb.frame...
```

there is also a [built in static method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/swing/SwingBuilder.html#lookAndFeel(java.lang.Object)) on SwingBuilder and this method accepts 'aliases' to the look and feel names:

```
SwingBuilder.lookAndFeel 'nimbus'

def sb = new SwingBuilder()
def addItmMenu = sb.frame...
```

or if you prefer to call it within your builder code (more concise but loses the fact that we are calling a static method):

```
def sb = new SwingBuilder()
def addItmMenu = sb.frame(...) {
  lookAndFeel 'nimbus'
  ...
}
```

where aliases like 'nimbus' above are defined in the [groovy LookAndFeelHelper class](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-swing/src/main/groovy/groovy/swing/LookAndFeelHelper.groovy#L40).

**edit**: the aliases in the groovy SwingBuilder call can also be fully qualified class names. The aliases are just there for convenience. An example:

```
SwingBuilder.lookAndFeel "de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaStandardLookAndFeel"
```

Comment: Great answer after modification. Answered accepted for the record.

Comment: If you can include something about custom L&F like **SyntheticaLookAndFeel** or it can't be done in groovy way ?